# Django map root to another url

Tags: django

Being new to Django app development I finally finished my app.
Now I would like the home page to load as the root.
Suppose my website is `www.foo.com`
Currently I do something like this

```
http://foo.com/home
```

to bring up the front page. I would like to bring the front page up without typing `/home`. I tried doing this to my urls.py by adding the first entry
however that does not seem to work. Any suggestions ?

```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^/$'    ,'main.views.promptLogin' , name="home"), #First page to show at index
        url(r'home$'    ,'main.views.promptLogin' , name="home"), #First page to show at index
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
url(r'^/$'    ,'main.views.promptLogin' , name="home")
```

corresponds to `http://foo.com//` because Django adds a `/` to the end of `foo.com` by default.

What you probably want is:

```
url(r'^$'    ,'main.views.promptLogin' , name="home")
```

which corresponds to

`http://foo.com/`

Comment: Actually, the first pattern corresponds to `http://foo.com//`, since Django implicitly adds the first slash to the pattern. `foo.com` and `foo.com/` lead to the same resource as far as Django is concerned, but you should not add a second slash on top of the first, implicit slash.

Comment: I didn't know that but that makes sense! I've updated my answer, thanks :)